# Vector of object pointers, initialisation

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm not very experienced with C++ yet, so bear with me if this is basic stuff.

I have some code like that below. `L` is an abstract class (it has a number of pure virtual functions), and `A`, `B` and `C` are regular classes all derived from `L`. There may be any number of these, and they are all different.

```
int main() {
    // ...

    std::vector<L*> ls(3) ; 

    ls[0] = new A ;
    ls[1] = new B ;
    ls[2] = new C ;

    int i ;
    for (i = 0 ; i < ls.size() ; i++) {
        if (ls[i]->h()) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

It works, but there really has to be a better way to initialise that vector. Right?

The vector is not supposed to change after it has been first initialised. I figure I can't make it const, however, because the various objects may themselves change internally. I picked a vector over a regular array because I don't want to manually keep track of its length (that proved error prone).

Ideally I'd like to pull the definition and initialisation of the vector out of `main` and preferably into a separate file that I can then `#include`. When I try that the compiler complains that it "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘=’ token". All the classes `A`, `B` and `C` have default constructors.

Also, I was under the impression that I have to manually `delete` anything created using `new`, but it won't delete `ls` with either `delete` or `delete[]`. If I try `delete ls;` the compiler complains that "type ‘class std::vector<L*, std::allocator<L*> >’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer".

Is the above even safe or does it cause some memory problems?

Comment: What exactly do the destructors of A, B and C do?

Comment: I haven't given them a destructor, so just whatever the compiler provides by default I suppose. Should I give them custom destructors?

Comment: The point is, if the destructors don't do anything special (like writing to a log file or something), you may get away without calling `delete` on the pointers at all, because the memory will be reclaimed when the program exits, anyway.

Comment: I see. I assume it doesn't hurt to delete them just to be safe, however? Especially if I were to add a destructor to one or all of them later.

Comment: No, it definitely does not hurt to call the destructors. I am just in doubt whether jumping through the hoops necessary to guarantee that the destructors get called is worth the additional complexity. Note that simply putting a bunch of `delete` statements at the bottom of the `main` function does not guarantee that the destructors will be called, because the flow of control may never reach those statements if an exception is thrown earlier on.

Comment: Hmm. Not certain how that could ever be completely prevented. Unless I were to wrap the entire `main` function in a `try` clause, and that might seem silly.

Comment: You prevent that by using smart pointers instead of raw pointers. Then you don't have to write `delete` in your code at all.

Comment: I'll have to look into that, so far I have only dealt with the standard library. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: `shared_ptr` will be part of the standard library of the next C++ standard. You can find it in section 20.7 of the [FDIS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3290.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but there really has to be a better way to initialise that vector. Right?

I don't think so, at least not without C++0x. Which way would you prefer? Your initialization code is completely fine.

> I figure I can't make it const, however, because the various objects may themselves change internally.

You can still make the vector itself `const`, only its member type cannot be a pointer to `const` then.

> I picked a vector over a regular array because I don't want to manually keep track of its length (that proved error prone).

You don't have to keep track of the length in constant arrays:

```
L* ls[] = { new A, new B, new C };
// with <boost/range/size.hpp>
std::size_t num = boost::size(ls);
// without Boost, more error-prone
// std::size_t num = sizeof ls / sizeof ls[0];
```

And often you don't need the size anyway, e.g. with Boost.Range.

> Ideally I'd like to pull the definition and initialisation of the vector out of main and preferably into a separate file that I can then #include.

That would violate the one-definition rule. You can put the declaration into a header file, but the definition has to go into a source file.

> Also, I was under the impression that I have to manually delete anything created using new, but it won't delete ls with either delete or delete[].

Your impression is correct, but you haven't created `ls` with `new`, only its *elements*. After using the vectors, you have to `delete` each of its elements, but not the vector itself.

The recommended alternative to STL containers holding polymorphic pointers is the [Boost pointer container library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/index.html).

Comment: Note that `L* ls = { new A, new B, new C };` is subtly different from `L ls[] = { new A, new B, new C };` in that the former *doesn't* know its own size (and your size expression will always return 1).

Comment: @Mark: Thanks, I missed the braces. The first form should even cause a compile error.

Comment: +1 for Boost Pointer Container library. Until we get `std::unique_ptr` in the main stream, it's the best way to manage containers of pointers, plus it's got some sugar coating :)

Comment: re. keeping track of the array length, your code is fragile and error-prone, in that it'll fail silently if the array decays to a pointer. The code will compile and run, it'll just return the wrong size. It can be made safer with a template function, but really, the OP's decision to just use a vector is simpler and safer

Comment: Ok, now I'm uncertain. I've got it to work just like I wanted with a regular array, as suggested by Philipp. Is that not safe? Should I use a vector or boost instead?

Comment: @jalf: I've added a version using Boost.Range which should give an error if a pointer is used.

Comment: @MCXXIII: If the vector works for you, don't hesitate to use it; the array initialization is a bit shorter, but the vector is safer and simpler to use.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it some thought. Just glad to know my initial solution wasn't totally wrong after all.

Comment: @MCXIII: in most cases, a vector is literally a zero-overhead solution. It doesn't cost you anything over an array. If the array can be stack-allocated (if the size is known at compile-time and the size is relatively small), then the array is cheaper to create than a vector (which always contains a heap-allocated array). But in actual use, it makes no difference. In general, stick with the simple and safe option (vector) until you know you need otherwise.

Comment: @jalf : Ah. Thanks. I got the impression vectors were massively more costly, but then, Stroustrup's book seems to give that impression about almost everything.

Comment: @MCXXIII: In general, the C++ containers are designed to be as efficient as their C counterparts. For example, vector access should (with a reasonably modern compiler) be as fast as C array access. The initialization is indeed a bit more costly, but this should be negligible since it's done only once.

Comment: I guess it does help greatly that I don't add a lot of elements to the vector during run-time.

Comment: Even if you did, performance wouldn't suffer that much: Adding elements at the end of a vector is an operation that runs in amortized constant time.

Answer (score 1):

You do indeed have to use delete on the objects you created.  You are calling delete on the vector not the objects.  Something like:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++){
    delete ls[i];
}
```

For your construction issue you could wrap them into a function and put that function in it's own header file.  You would have to make sure to include all of the relevant classes header files as well.

```
void init_vector(std::vector<LS*> & v){
    ls[0] = new A ; 
    ls[1] = new B ;
    ls[2] = new C ;
}
```

Comment: The deleting works now. I was getting a little bit nervous about that, so thanks. About the initialisation, is there really not way to do something like `std::vector<L*> ls = {new A, new B, new C} ;`?

Comment: @MCXXIII Check out the boost assignment library.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html  That may do what you need

Comment: Thanks. I seems there are a few solutions I might consider.

Answer (score 0):

If C++11 is acceptable, you might be better off with an `std::array` instead of `std::vector`:

```
std::array<L *, 3> = {new A(), new B(), new C()};
```

Comment: I think I shouldn't be too "modern", for the sake of portability. But thanks.

Comment: The C++0x `array` should be equivalent to Boost's `array`—there are quite a few class templates in C++0x that have been inspired by Boost.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the size at compile time, I suggest using an `array` instead of a `vector`. Using the class template `array` instead of a C-style array gives you the benefit of a standard container interface, just like a `vector`. That is, you can call `size()` on the array and obtain iterators and so on.

And to make sure you don't forget to `delete` the objects, I suggest using smart pointers:

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

boost::array<boost::shared_ptr<L>, 3> ls = { {
    boost::make_shared<A>(),
    boost::make_shared<B>(),
    boost::make_shared<C>(),
} };
```

Modern compilers ship their own versions of `array` and `shared_ptr` in the standard library:

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>

std::array<std::shared_ptr<L>, 3> ls = { {
    std::make_shared<A>(),
    std::make_shared<B>(),
    std::make_shared<C>(),
} };
```

Note that the outermost braces are technically not needed, but leaving them out might produce compiler warnings, at least that's what happens on my compiler.

> Ideally I'd like to pull the definition and initialization of the vector out of `main` and preferably into a separate file that I can then `#include`

In that case, you need a header file with a *declaration* and an implementation file with a *definition* of `ls`:

```
// file ls.h

#ifndef LS_H
#define LS_H

#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

extern boost::array<boost::shared_ptr<L>, 3> ls;

#endif

// file ls.cpp

#include "ls.h"
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

boost::array<boost::shared_ptr<L>, 3> ls = { {
    boost::make_shared<A>(),
    boost::make_shared<B>(),
    boost::make_shared<C>(),
} };
```

Comment: Thanks. And I can never seem to get the definition/declaration thing straight, I always mix them up. Sorry about that.